# Regex not giving me the correct output

Tags: c#, regex

Here's my Regex:

```
var GetNotes = new Regex(@"(?<=[A-Z0-9/]</strong>)([\s\S]*?)(?=</td>)").Matches(set);
```

here is a brief snippet of the document it scans through

> </strong> In touch, tracked leaders when blundered 27th, 3rd 2 out, ridden to 
>   challenge approaching elbow, stayed on to lead inside final 100 yards, 
>   going away towards finish                        </td>

Here's a piece of my code:

```
String NotesAtLine1 = File.ReadLines(FractionTwoData).ElementAtOrDefault(NotesPositionLine);
File.AppendAllText(NotesData, NotesAtLine1 + Notes + Environment.NewLine);
NotesPositionLine++;
```

how do I get the Regex that it has found to put it in one line. 
the `FractionTwoData`  contains information but I want to add the found text to the end of that line all one line

Comment: Please add the correct language tag. I'm guessing this is [tag:c#]?

Comment: sorry, yes...  its c#

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML with regex?

Comment: yes, i've got all the html backed up on my laptop and trying to get all the data I need. ive succeded somewhat but it doesent seem to read all the html files